# Добавление символов в определенном месте

Tags: notepad++

Есть документ в котором часто встречается во многих строках текста 
определенный повторяющийся символ "#". Необходимо найти все строки в документе где содержится данный символ # и заключить последующий текст, который расположен на следующей строке в кавычки.  т.е. текст которому необходимы кавычки всегда находится на нижней строке по отношению к символу #.

В документе присутствуют пустые строки и строки, где нет этого символа.

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно это реализовать в Notepad++ ?

---

Добавил фрагмент текста на базе стихотворения(три четверостишия) для примера:

```
Встало солнышко пораньше,
Искупалося в реке
И уселось на # лужайке –
На зеленом бугорке.

Темно – алые гвоздики
Накалились # докрасна!
Загорела на припеке
Одноногая сосна.

Зарумянилась # малина,
Раскраснелся в поле мак.
В камышах кричат лягушки:
— Жарко как! Жарко как!
```

Теги нужно поставить от начала след. строки за символом и желательно до пустой строки, отделяющей четверостишья. Первые кавычки должны взять текст "На зеленом бугорке". Вторые кавычки берут уже две нижние строчки. А третьи кавычки берут три нижних строчки. Т.е. в этом примере желательно получить три тега с кавычками. Если нельзя обойтись тремя тегами, то подходит также альтерн. вариант с выделением каждой отдельной строки в кавычки- тогда тегов с кавычками будет уже не три, а шесть

Comment: К сожалению, никак.

Comment: Можете подсказать? Как правильно прописать поле замена, при нахождение данного символа в ручную. В ситуации когда необходимо поставить просто одну хотябы кавычку или другой условный символ. Чтобы условный символ вставлялся всегда в начало следующей строки документа, по отношению к символу #.

Comment: @Igor приведите пример фрагмента, пожалуйста.

Comment: UModeL, добавил стихотворение. Скопируйте его себе в блокнот пожалуйста, там три четверостишия для примера.Теги нужно поставить от начала след. строки за символом и желательно до пустой строки, отделяющей четверостишья. Первые кавычки должны взять текст "На зеленом бугорке". Вторые кавычки берут уже две нижние строчки. А третьи кавычки берут три нижних строчки. Т.е. в этом примере желательно получить три тега с кавычками. Если нельзя обойтись тремя тегами, то подходит также альтерн. вариант с выделением каждой отдельной строки в кавычки- тогда тегов с кавычками будет уже не три, а шесть.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В окне "Заменить" в поле "Найти" пишем это:

```
#([\s\S]*?)\n([\s\S]*?)\r\n\r\n
```

в поле "Заменить на" пишем это:

```
#\1\n"\2"\r\n\r\n
```

Режим поиска - "регулярные выражения".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Траблшутинг: если в файле в качестве абзаца используется не CR LF (можно посмотреть активировав показ непечатаемых символов; кнопка ¶ ), то `\r\n` нужно заменить на `\r` или на `\n`.

Comment: Эникейщик, спасибо вам большое! Проверил сработало.